# Quantifiers are not working in my regex tester

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I created a simple regEx tester like this;

```
var expression = dialog.element.find(".input-regex");
var testString = dialog.element.find(".input-text");
var result = dialog.element.find(".output-text");

function highlight(e) {
  debugger;
    let searched = expression.val();
  if (searched !== "") {
    let text = $(".input-text").val();
    let re = new RegExp(searched,"g");
        let newText = text.replace(re, `<span style="background-color:yellow;">${searched}</span>`);
        result.html(newText);
  }
}

dialog.element.on("change",".input-regex",function(){
debugger;
var pattern = new RegExp(expression.val());
result.val(pattern.exec(testString.val()));
highlight();
});
```

Here's a Stack Snippet version of it:

```js
var expression = $(".input-regex");
var testString = $(".input-text");
var result = $(".output-text");

function highlight(e) {
    let searched = expression.val();
    if (searched !== "") {
        let text = $(".input-text").val();
        let re = new RegExp(searched, "g");
        let newText = text.replace(re, `<span style="background-color:yellow;">${searched}</span>`);
        result.html(newText);
    }
}

$(document.body).on("change", ".input-regex", function(event) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(expression.val());
    result.val(pattern.exec(testString.val()));
    highlight();
});
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Regex:
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="input-regex">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Text:
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="input-text">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    Output:
    <br>
    <div class="output-text"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Its working for simple expressions, but when I use quantifiers it fails.

[image]

Any help is appreciated, I spent way too much time on this and still can't find the problem.

Comment: What's a "reference initial"? Do you mean a [quantifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers)?

Comment: yes quantifiers,  im sorry , I just used a dictionary and that was the closest match for what I tried to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `searched` text in the yellow spans. Instead, use the text matched by the regular expression using the `$&` token with `replace`:

```
let newText = text.replace(re, `<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>`);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

Live Example:

```js
var expression = $(".input-regex");
var testString = $(".input-text");
var result = $(".output-text");

function highlight(e) {
    let searched = expression.val();
    if (searched !== "") {
        let text = $(".input-text").val();
        let re = new RegExp(searched, "g");
        let newText = text.replace(re, `<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>`);
        result.html(newText);
    }
}

$(document.body).on("change", ".input-regex", function(event) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(expression.val());
    result.val(pattern.exec(testString.val()));
    highlight();
});
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Regex:
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="input-regex">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Text:
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="input-text">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    Output:
    <br>
    <div class="output-text"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If at some stage you want to color-code capture groups, their contents are available via `$0`, `$1`, etc. — although at that point you'd probably be better off using [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and using the match information it provides, since that includes indexes.